# Setting up example app within directory path

Tags: angularjs, shopify

I have a Shopify store, which uses the liquid templating engine. I'm trying to setup a blog on within this site / theme.

I would like to design the blog with angular. The blog has it's own directory within the site, and it's not on a subdomain of it's own.

- http://holstee.com/blogs/themes
- http://holstee.com/blogs/themes/111111-article-title

I'm wondering if this is something that can be done with angular, and why it's the example that's up isn't binding? Is it a base url thing?

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do with Javascript that is specific to rendering a Shopify blog?

Comment: @DavidLazar Render out the entire blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wondering why your example on that page isnt working,  bring up your Javascript console (Command + J) and you'll see the error.     You need to initialize the myApp module.

Something like

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

The error can be found here:
http://tinyurl.com/mbvhc5a

And to answer your question,  yes you can use angular for your blog, but the question is more likely to be is it the right choice? For most blogs, the answer would be no, unless your planning a high amount of user interaction with the UI.

Comment: Thanks @Cheyne, that was another example I was using, obviously needed dependancies. My real problem was that the liquid server was processing the curly braces, so I had to change the default in angular, or wrap the doc in `{% raw %}`.